# Drawing a path on canvas using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to draw a path on canvas using a for loop. I do not want to draw the normal way, I need to use a for loop. Now, the coords work perfectly, but the problem is that the last click draws lines to each of the previous clicks, while I only want to draw a path. I know that I should make a copy of the "i" but I can't make it work.

```
function draw(event) {

var coords = getMouseCoords(event);
xpos = coords[0];
ypos = coords[1];

for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
    context.lineTo(myArray[i].x, myArray[i].y);
    context.stroke();
}
myArray.push({x:coords[0], y:coords[1]});
}
```

HTML

```
<canvas width="600" height="480" id="myCanvas" onclick="draw(event)"></canvas>
```

Could you take a look at it and see if you can fix the problem? No JQuery please.

Thanks,

Marco

Comment: seems you just forgot `context.closePath();` before `context.stroke();`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. I'm not really interested in closing the path, I only need to draw a path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to use `for` loop, solution below draws path each time `function draw` is invoked, but keep in mind that it makes sense only when `canvas` is cleared before drawing. Otherwise you could draw line from current click location to last element of array and the result would be the same.

Also replace `var coords = [event.clientX, event.clientY];` with call to your function, I have changed it to make snippet work.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var myArray = [];

function draw(event) {
  var coords = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
  xpos = coords[0];
  ypos = coords[1];

  myArray.push({
    x: coords[0],
    y: coords[1]
  });

  if (myArray.length > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(myArray[i].x, myArray[i].y);
      context.lineTo(myArray[i + 1].x, myArray[i + 1].y);
      context.stroke();
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="480" id="myCanvas" onclick="draw(event)"></canvas>
```

Comment: That works alright, the only problem that I can see is that it draws lines on top of each other while looping

Comment: So why do you say "..I need to use a for loop" ??

Comment: Because, I have a circle that follows the cursor onmousemove and, as you said, I clear the canvas everytime

Comment: It does in my example, but as you clear the canvas it will not be problem for you, lines will be drawn only once when it's cleared.